# Combining raw HTML and a rails variable in a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a link_to that looks like this

```
<%= link_to site.name, site %>
```

I want to add a font icon from bootstrap into the anchor text, but when I try to use `raw()` for that, I can't figure out the syntax for including the `site.name` hook.

This is what I'm trying:

```
<%= link_to raw("<i class="icon-hdd"></i> site.name"), site %>
```

That's not working.  How do I change that line to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the do syntax?

```
<%= link_to site do %>
  <i class="icon-hdd"> </i> <%= site.name%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to interpolate `site_name` into the string.

```
<%= link_to raw("<i class='icon-hdd'></i> #{site.name}"), site %>
```

Comment: Also be careful with the quotes - you had double quotes inside double quotes which is not valid.